# "ValueError: Mime type rendering requires nbformat>=4.2.0 but it is not installed " when plotting in jupyter

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, plotly, data-visualization

It threw me an error when I tried to plot a chart in the jupyter notebook. I have followed the instructions who met the similar problems such as "pip install --upgrade nbformat" or "conda install -c conda-forge nbformat" but neither resolved the problem.

BTW, I have upgraded my jupyter.

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")
df["world"] = "world" # in order to have a single root node
fig = px.treemap(df, path=['world', 'continent', 'country'], values='pop',
                  color='lifeExp', hover_data=['iso_alpha'],
                  color_continuous_scale='RdBu',
                  color_continuous_midpoint=np.average(df['lifeExp'], weights=df['pop']))

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
fig.show()
```

Comment: it's almost certainly an issue with your jupyter install.  code works for me.  `import nbformat
nbformat.__version__` returns 5.1.3 in my case

Comment: I have upgraded jupyter but still cant figure out the problem

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem:

```
pip install "jupyterlab>=3" "ipywidgets>=7.6"
```

See [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py)

Comment: thanks but still not working for me